# I am getting Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

I am currently trying to include a form onto my homepage where the user can leave a comment and then include the output of that form below so visitors can see all the messages.
I am currently getting the following error when i submit a comment:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Here is the controller:

```
 <?php

use Desk\Forms\MessageForm; 
use Desk\Records\MessageRecord;
use Desk\Repositories\MessageRepository;

class MessageController extends BaseController
{

protected $messageForm;

public function __construct(MessageForm $messageForm, MessageRepository $messageRepository,
  MessageRecord $messageRecord)
{
    $this->messageForm = $messageForm;
    $this->messageRepository = $messageRepository;
    $this->messageRecord = $messageRecord;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /messages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}



public function show($comment)
{
    $message_id = $this->messageRepository->find($comment);
    return View::make('comments.show')->with('comment', $message_id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * POST /messaages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all() ;
    $this->messageForm->validate($data);

    $messageRecord = new MessageRecord;
    $messageRecord->comment = $data['comment'];

    Return "Comment created";
}
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::resource('/message', 'MessageController');
```

Comment: I assume you are using s REST bundle of some sort?  Is your form using PUT?

Comment: I don't have a controller for my form.

Comment: Look at your html source code itself.  What is the method parameter in your form element set to?  Somewhere along the line the http method is being set.  And what REST Symfony 2 bundle are you using?  And why is your route resource named 'messages' but your comments have 'message'?

Comment: I am using symphony 2.4